# 5.2 and Windows 10 compatibility release

Tags: acumatica

I know this isnt a dev question per se, but is there a timeline on a 5.2 build that can be installed on Win 10?

I think the issue i am seeing is just with the installer so an in place upgrade to Win 10 might work fine, but a clean install fails as it doesnt acknowledge IIS 10 or whatever version comes with Win 10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official answer - Windows 10 is not yet supported by the currently available Acumatica ERP installers, however the issue has already been fixed internally (AC-56069 - fixed in 4.20.2262, 5.10.0785, 5.20.1012 and newer). Following workaround can be used in the meantime:

1. Download the Orca tool to edit the MSI file: http://adriank.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Orca.zip
2. Open the
   MSI file using this tool (might be able to right click on MSI and
   open with Orca)
3. Go to the LaunchCondition table
4. Drop/delete the IIS version condition (inside MSI, the LaunchCondition entry is IISVERSION >="#7"; system does a string comparison and "10" is
   smaller than "7")
5. Save and close Orca
6. Run the setup

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you an "official" answer but I can give you a work around.

If you download a utility called [LessMSI](http://lessmsi.activescott.com/) you can extract the installation files.  They will come out in a folder called "SourceDir".  Simply take these and replace the files in your default installation folder or run them from another location.

Then you can proceed as normal.

The installer only checks if pre-reqs are installed and then copy's the files to the output location.   If you have IIS already setup with dotnet support then the rest will be fine.

I do this frequently if I have to install a site with a specific version in order to upgrade or test a client's snapshot.

I have 4.1,4.2,5.1,5.2 running on my Windows 10 workstation as I type